# textarea text into sql column

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, textarea

If I use a textbox I have no issues getting data into sql. I'd like to use a textarea with autowrap and all that. But when I change the `<input type="text" id="au_id">` to `<textarea name="au_id">` I can't get the `.value` of `au_id.Value` code listed below.

All I want is to swap single line text box for multiline textarea and still onclick get my lines posted in sql. Some of the names/id's make no sense for what they go to, I copied most of the code from Microsoft's site, and making changes as I go.

code:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Text"%>

<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    #au_id
    {
        height: 103px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<script language="VB" runat="server" >
Dim MyConnection As SqlConnection

Sub Page_Load(Src As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' Create a connection to the "EMR" SQL database located on 
  ' the local computer.
    MyConnection = New SqlConnection("server=localhost;" _
       & "database=EMR;Trusted_Connection=Yes")
    ' Check whether this page is a  postback. If it is not 
    ' a  postback, call a custom BindGrid function.
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        BindGrid()
    End If
End Sub

' Implement an AddAuthor_Click function. This function does some data 
' validation on the input form and builds a parameterized command containing 
' all the fields of the input form.  Then it executes this command to the 
' database and tests (using the try command) whether the data was added. 
' Finally, it rebinds the DataGrid to show the new data.
Sub AddAuthor_Click(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim myCommand As SqlCommand
    Dim insertCmd As String

    If (au_fname.Value = "" Or au_lname.Value = "" _
       Or phone.Value = "") Then
        Message.InnerHtml = "ERROR: Null values not allowed for " _
           & "Author ID, Name or Phone"
        Message.Style("color") = "red"
        BindGrid()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Build a SQL INSERT statement string for all the input-form
    ' field values.
    insertCmd = "insert into VisitData values (@Subjective, @Objective, @Assessment," _
       & "@Plan, @HT, @WT, @BP, @ServiceDate, @Diagnosis);"
    ' Initialize the SqlCommand with the new SQL string.
    myCommand = New SqlCommand(insertCmd, myConnection)
    ' Create new parameters for the SqlCommand object and
    ' initialize them to the input-form field values.
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Subjective", _
       SqlDbType.VarChar, 8000))
    myCommand.Parameters("@Subjective").Value = au_id.Value
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Objective", _
       SqlDbType.VarChar, 8000))
    myCommand.Parameters("@Objective").Value = au_lname.Value
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Assessment", _
       SqlDbType.VarChar, 8000))
    myCommand.Parameters("@Assessment").Value = au_fname.Value
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Plan", _
       SqlDbType.Char, 8000))
    myCommand.Parameters("@Plan").Value = phone.Value
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@HT", _
       SqlDbType.VarChar, 40))
    myCommand.Parameters("@HT").Value = address.Value
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@WT", _
       SqlDbType.VarChar, 20))
    myCommand.Parameters("@WT").Value = city.Value
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@BP", _
       SqlDbType.Char, 10))
    myCommand.Parameters("@BP").Value = state.Value
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ServiceDate", _
       SqlDbType.Char, 10))
    myCommand.Parameters("@ServiceDate").Value = zip.Value
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Diagnosis", _
       SqlDbType.VarChar, 20))
    myCommand.Parameters("@Diagnosis").Value = contract.Value
    myCommand.Connection.Open()
    ' Test whether the new row can be added and  display the 
    ' appropriate message box to the user.
    Try
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Message.InnerHtml = "<b>Record Added</b><br>"
    Catch ex As SqlException
        If ex.Number = 2627 Then
            Message.InnerHtml = "ERROR: A record already exists with " _
               & "the same primary key"
        Else
            Message.InnerHtml = "ERROR: Could not add record, please " _
               & "ensure the fields are correctly filled out"
            Message.Style("color") = "red"
        End If
    End Try

    myCommand.Connection.Close()
    BindGrid()
End Sub

' BindGrid connects to the database and implements a SQL 
' SELECT query to get all the data in the "Authors" table 
' of the database.
Sub BindGrid()
    Dim myConnection As SqlConnection
    Dim myCommand As SqlDataAdapter
    ' Create a connection to the "EMR" SQL database located on 
    ' the local computer.
    myConnection = New SqlConnection("server=localhost;" _
       & "database=EMR;Trusted_Connection=Yes")
    ' Connect to the SQL database using a SQL SELECT query to get all 
    ' the data from the "Authors" table.
    myCommand = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM VisitData", _
       myConnection)
    ' Create and fill a new DataSet.
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    myCommand.Fill(ds)
    ' Bind the DataGrid control to the DataSet.  will remain hidden 
    MyDataGrid.DataSource = ds
    MyDataGrid.DataBind()
 End Sub
</script>
<body style="font: 10pt verdana">
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
<h3><font face="Verdana">Inserting Visit Data</font></h3>
<table width="95%">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
      <ASP:DataGrid id="MyDataGrid" runat="server"
        Width="700"
        BackColor="#ccccff" 
        BorderColor="black"
        ShowFooter="false" 
        CellPadding=3 
        CellSpacing="0"
        Font-Name="Verdana"
        Font-Size="8pt"
        HeaderStyle-BackColor="#aaaadd"
        Visible="false"
        EnableViewState="false"

      />
    </td>
<body style="font: 10pt verdana">
    <td valign="top">
      <table style="font: 8pt verdana">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#aaaadd" style="font:10pt verdana">
            Add Visit Info:</td>
        </tr>
         <td>Subjective: </td>
          <td>
          <input type="text" id="au_id" value="" runat="server" maxlength="8000" 
                  style="overflow: scroll; white-space: normal;" />

          </td>
          <tr>
          <td nowrap>Objective: </td>
          <td><input type="text" id="au_lname" value="" 
            runat="server"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr nowrap>
          <td>Assessment: </td>
          <td><input type="text" id="au_fname" value="" 
            runat="server"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Plan: </td>
          <td><input type="text" id="phone" value="" 
            runat="server"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>HT: </td>
          <td><input type="text" id="address" 
            value="" runat="server"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>WT: </td>
          <td><input type="text" id="city" value="" 
            runat="server"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>BP: </td>
          <td>
            <input type = "text" id="state" runat="server">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td nowrap>Date of Service: </td>
          <td><input type="text" id="zip" value=""
             runat="server"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Diagnosis: </td>
          <td>
          <Input type="text" id="contract" value="" runat="server">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style="padding-top:15">
            <input id="Submit1" type="submit" OnServerClick="AddAuthor_Click"
              value="Add Visit" runat="server">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" style="padding-top:15" align="center">
            <span id="Message" EnableViewState="false" 
              style="font: arial 11pt;" runat="server"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

**To change to a textarea, you need to keep the `id="au_id"` and `runat="server"` attributes**

```
<input type="text" id="au_id" value="" runat="server" maxlength="8000" style="overflow: scroll; white-space: normal;" />
```

Becomes

```
<textarea runat="server" id="au_id" rows="4" cols="8">default text</textarea>
```

Note: Remove maxlength

**To access the textarea value from your VB.NET code:**

```
Reponse.Write(au_id.value)
```

Comment: @Connie Chichuk - please be sure to accept hamlin11's answer so he gets the credit (and rep). :)

Answer (score 0):

Upon having this problem myself and spending some time trying to fix the problems with solutions from many many forum posts i managed to fix this same problem. Of all the forums I checked the problem was getting the string value from the textarea into an sql `INSERT` statement using the `$_POST` php superglobal variable

The only way I can see that actually works and doesnt throw up any errors is to ignore the column names when writing the `INSERT` statement.
So instead of:

```
"INSERT INTO tbl_dbTable ( Colummn1, Colummn2...) VALUES( '$_POST[textarea]', 'Value2'..)"
```

simply use:

```
"INSERT INTO tbl_dbTable VALUES( '$_POST[textarea]', 'Value2'..)"
```

The only downside is you MUST then list values for ALL the columns in the table, but it fixes the problem of getting the textarea value into an sql column.

hope this helps